# How to change mongodb default cleanup time for TTL index?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to set TTL around 2-3 months so its clearly infeasible to check after every 60 sec for TTL indexex. I want to reduce overhead by checking TTL once in a day. Is there any way to manually/programmatically define this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my knowledge it is impossible to do this. Some time ago I was looking for this option but have not found anything apart of [disabling it completely](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.ttlMonitorEnabled).

I am inclined to think that this is impossible to modify because in [TTL documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/) it is told explicitly that:

> The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60
>   seconds.

and there is no parameter in [server configuration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/) which makes anything similar.

**P.S.** I understand that you see this as a waste of resources, but I would start to worry about it only when I will see a bottleneck regarding to it.

**P.P.S** and if you would found that this is a bottleneck, you can implement your own cleanup (put a script which removes all documents later than some timestamp) and put it once per day on cron job.

Comment: Thanks Dali. I will create a cron job to do this but I'm afraid whether it will produce a lock issue on the DB or not.